# Eclipse Installation Error - NullPointerException and HTTP Proxy Authentication

Tags: http, proxy, nullpointerexception

I am trying to install Eclipse at my work and I am running into an error. I will paste the logs below, but before I do that, let me give a brief background of my problem.

I am trying to install Eclipse on a laptop from my company at the facility where I work. They indeed use proxy identification and even with admin privileges, I cannot seem to install Eclipse. The first error I get when running the Eclipse Installation is a NullPointerException error. The logs are:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl$AuthorizationHandlerImpl.reauthorize(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:772)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl$ConnectionHandler.process(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:1674)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl.createInputStream(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:319)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createInputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:360)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1314)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.handleArchiveRedirection(SetupCoreUtil.java:546)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.configureResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:348)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.configureResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:174)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.createResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.SetupWizard.(SetupWizard.java:167)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.SetupWizard.(SetupWizard.java:159)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.Installer.(Installer.java:40)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.run(InstallerApplication.java:222)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.start(InstallerApplication.java:408)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)

After continuing on by clicking an "Update" button or "Ok", I get another error. This time, its an "internal error. HTTP proxy authentication required". The logs for THAT is below:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication$6$2.run(InstallerApplication.java:484)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: HTTP Proxy
>   Authentication Required:
>   http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/products/repository/content.xml     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:246)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:89)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:63)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:770)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:117)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:409)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:201)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:476)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:105)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1613)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:428)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63) Caused
>   by: org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.BrowseFileTransferException: Proxy
>   Authentication Required   at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:291)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
>     ... 1 more

**Solution I have tried:**
Going to eclipse.ini and typing 
`-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4` but it did not work.

Any solutions will help. Personally, I believe it is ultimately the proxy settings that is preventing me from installing Eclipse, as I am also having the same problem with opening Unity. (I could install Unity, but cannot sign in). Thank you.